# AngularJS can't read response HTTP Headers from NodeJS server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, web

I am currently trying to make a Token-Based auth between a NodeJS server and AngularJS client.

In other words: Server generates token, sends to client in http header, client receives and sets that token to be sent in the next request (in the http header), when the request gets to the server it's checked if it contains a previously sent token. Repeat.

The problem is I'm not able to read the headers from AngularJS, even though I can see the header was successfully set in the response, through Chrome's console.

So far, I've got an AngularJS interceptor (What I've been told I should do) like this:

```
angular
    .module('injector', [])
    .factory('sessionInjector', function(){

      var injectedSession = {
          response: function(res) {

                console.log("RESPONSE: " + JSON.stringify(res.config.headers));

              return res;
          };

      return injectedSession;
});
```

And this is the output:

```
RESPONSE: {"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}
```

I've just started with AngularJS and I'm a little lost. Hope I didn't mess up something really basic.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that you are printing the right response?

Comment: I am, I answered my own question below, after hours of research I found the answer on another stackoverflow thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that changing

```
response
```

for

```
'response'
```

made the trick.

I don't know why that did happen.

Answer (score 2):

When you hit a http request it looks something like below :-

```
$http.get("your URL",)
      .success(function (data,status, headers, config) {
        console.log(headers('Content-Encoding'));
      })
      .error(function (error) {
          canceller.reject(error);
      });
}
```

And you will receive response from server with other detail in callback, and you can headers like above.

I hope it will help you.
Thanks

Comment: Isn't that to make a one and only request? Or does that allow me to intercept every response that gets to the client?

Comment: you can make a global service for request and use that service every time you request a server.

Comment: like  module.factory("deferredService", ['$http', function($http){
    var service = {};

    service.get = function (url) {
      $http.get(url)
          .success(function (data,status, headers, config) {
            console.log(headers('Content-Encoding'));
          })
          .error(function (error) {
              canceller.reject(error);
          });
    }
    return service;
  
}]);


Include this service in your Angular controller and call like

deferredService.get("your URL")
  .then(function (response) {
    
});

Comment: Thank you for your help, thanks to you I was able to validate that the headers were arriving properly to the server.

I'm going to try to implement what you've just told me to see if it fixes the remaining errors.